# Foreach Undefined Index

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

Am trying to loop through an array,with `print_r` I get the array below but am getting

> "Notice: Undefined index: name"

error,  when I ran my loop, dunno what am doing wrong?
Kindly help

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 1
                [name] => Paul
                [email] => 32
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 2
                [name] => Allen
                [email] => 25
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 3
                [name] => Teddy
                [email] => 23
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 4
                [name] => 4
                [email] => Mark
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 5
                [name] => Paul
                [email] => 32
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 6
                [name] => Allen
                [email] => 25
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 7
                [name] => Teddy
                [email] => 23
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 8
                [name] => 4
                [email] => Mark
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 9
                [name] => Paul
                [email] => 32
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 10
                [name] => Allen
                [email] => 25
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 11
                [name] => Teddy
                [email] => 23
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 12
                [name] => 4
                [email] => Mark
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 13
                [name] => Paul
                [email] => 32
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 14
                [name] => Allen
                [email] => 25
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 15
                [name] => Teddy
                [email] => 23
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 16
                [name] => 4
                [email] => Mark
            )

        [16] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 17
                [name] => Paul
                [email] => ibraq22@yahooo.com
            )

        [17] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 18
                [name] => Opeyemi Adam
                [email] => resfvr@yahoo.com
            )

        [18] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 19
                [name] => Opeyemi Adam
                [email] => info@ckdigital.net
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 20
                [name] => Paul
                [email] => ibraq22@yahooo.com
            )

    )

)
```

My PHP Loop  is below

```
    foreach ($retr as $page) {
        echo $page['name'];
        //var_dump($page);
    }
```

Regards

Comment: what is the result of `var_dump($page);` ?

Comment: You have a multidimensional array, you either need to loop around `$retr[0]`, or have a second `foreach` loop to iterate over the first level.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is multidimentional, being a single element array containing a further 19 child elements.

If you just want to itterate the child elements, then run the loop over the top level elelemt, not the parent array:

```
foreach ($retr[0] as $page) {...}
```